# GMSStyleSpans change color in a range

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-polyline

I have been trying to change the color of a part of polyline using GMSStyleSpan but its not working.

```
[GMSStyleSpan spanWithColor:[UIColor redColor] segments:10];
```

Converts first 10 points to red color

---

```
NSArray *styles = @[[GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]];
NSArray *lengths = @[@10, @20];
polyline.spans = GMSStyleSpans(rectangle.path, styles, lengths, kGMSLengthRhumb);
```

Creates alternate white and black pattern after every 10 coordinates starting from 10th coordinate.

---

There's nothing mentioned in the documentation about how to change the color of a polyline in a range. I have all the data with me, such as, if there are 100 coordinates, I know that from 80 to 90 I have to change the color.

Please assist !

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I had to create separate Polyline objects based on each color.